# PyQt: Drag'n'Drop based Scrabble UI

Tags: drag-and-drop, pyqt, qlayout

I've written a simple Scrabble game with a simple Bot and Human part which can interact using consolebased I/O. Although there is already a Qt based overview of the current situation in the game: A simple custom `QWidget` which simply paints everything. No interaction or anything fancy yet.

[image: My current, pretty good working, solution]
<sub>(source: [b52 at reaktor42.de](http://reaktor42.de/%7Eb52/shots/2011-06-16-201249_1920x1200_scrot.png))</sub>

My problem is that I would like to remove the consolebased interaction and switch to a new Drag'n'Drop based approach, but I'm not that familiar with PyQt and GUI development in general.

Therefor my question is, what would be a good way to go? Creating custom Layouts for Board and Rack and custom Letter Widget which would be dragable?

Thanks in advance
Oli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks pretty good! If you need to actually move things around on the screen using the mouse, I think the [Graphics View Framework](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/graphicsview.html) would be a better way to go than widgets.

Comment: Yeah looks like. Do you got some more hints about how to use it? I'm new to this but I learn very fast once I got some examples or usage information.

Comment: Ok, seems I found I way which is good enough to do what I want, here a little [demonstration](http://reaktor42.de/~b52/public/scrabble_board.ogv)

Comment: It's a pretty broad topic so you pretty much just have to jump in and play around with it until it starts to make sense :)